# How to order a list in sublists in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, sublist

I have a list like this:

```
(4 5 6 3 12 22 4 4 55 43 1 4 0)
```

and want an output like this:

```
((4 5 6) (3) (12 22) (4) (4 55) (43) (1 4) (0))
```

I think you can guess the order, it has an ascending order, I'm totally new with Lisp and need some help

Comment: So you want to start a new sublist every time the current element is lower than the previous element? Does that description make it easier for you to figure out how to code it?

Comment: `(4 55 43)` is not ascending.

Comment: @Svante sorry that was a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible solution in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

```
(defun ascending-partitions (list)
  (let ((indices (mappend (do if (>= @1 @2) (list @3))
                          list (cdr list) (range 1))))
    (split list indices)))
```

We obtain the numeric index positions of the elements in the list which are not greater than their predecessors; then we use the [`split`](http://nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-02FD4882) function to cut the list into pieces at these indices.

Calculating the indices is done by processing three lists through the [`mappend`](http://nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-0202F92F) function: the original `list`, in parallel with that same list with the first element removed `(cdr list)`, and an infinite list of incrementing integers starting at 1 produced by `(range 1)`.

The [`do`](http://nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-0068EA9D) macro writes an anonymous function for us, in which the `@1`, `@2` and `@3` variables embedded in the expression are its three arguments, in that order. `mappend` call this function with successive triplets of values taken from the lists in parallel. Thus `@1` takes values from `list`, `@2` takes successive values from `(cdr list)` and `@3` takes successive values from the list of integers.  Whenever `@1` is at least as large as its successor `@2`, we collect the positional index `@3` into a one-element list. `mappend` catenates these together.

In contrast to this, we could write a more direct solution that requires more code, but makes better use of machine resources:

```
(defun ascending-partitions (list)
  (let (partition output prev)
    (each ((item list))         ;; use (dolist (item list)  in Common Lisp
      (when (and prev (<= item prev))
        (when partition
          (push (nreverse partition) output)
          (set partition nil))) ;; use setf or setq in Common Lisp
      (push item partition)
      (set prev item))          ;; ditto
    (when partition
      (push (nreverse partition) output))
    (nreverse output)))
```

Comment: thank you very much that was really helpful I understand now some things...