# How to make sublists of a list in Lisp?

Tags: list, lisp

I want to make sublists of a given list when my first number is lower than my next number. I already wrote something but it's not working, it says 'NIL ist not a real number' I hope someone can help me further

```
(defun order(lst)
       (cond ((null lst) nil)
            (t (if (< (car lst) (cadr lst))
                (cons (car lst) (cadr lst))) (order (rest lst)))))


(print(order '(1 4 5 12 22 34 7 9 0)))

 //Output should be this -->((1 4 5) (12 22 34) (7 9) (0))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to order a list in sublists in Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56436039/how-to-order-a-list-in-sublists-in-lisp)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your question from several days ago. Shouldn't the output be `((1 4 5 12 22 34) (7 9) (0))`?  `12` is greater than `5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this seems like homework just some pointers:

1. Right now you are only forming a new list with cons that is exactly two long. Think about how you want the recursion to go to either extend this new list if necessary or include new elements before "closing" it.
2. You don't call any further recursion when you find a sorted pair. Your code just ends.
3. If the two compared elements are NOT sorted you do nothing with the old head, you just drop it. Overall there is no "outer" list generated in the course of your algorithm.
4. Right now cadr might run into the end of the list. So < will be called on a number and nil which leads to disaster.

Comment: thanks, I wrote now this : ```(defun order(lst)
       (cond ((null lst) nil)
          ((null (cadr lst)) nil)
           ((< (car lst) (cadr lst)) (cons(car lst) (order (rest lst))))
           ((> (car lst) (cadr lst)) (cons(car lst) (order (rest lst))))
            (t(order(rest lst)))))```
It's working better but I get the list back and not the sublists...

Comment: @newlearner You never close your inner lists. Right now you don't have any equal numbers to each others in your example anyway so you never run into the last case. But the bigger and smaller case do exactly the same, they just add the current head to a new list - so in the end you just rebuild your old list. Every time you meet a smaller number you need to "close" the previous list construction process and start a new one, but right now your < and > are the same.